# Handling NSNotificationCenter notification is causing bad_access

Tags: nstimer, uiwindow, nsnotificationcenter

I am subclassing the UIWindow of my app then when there is no activity from user I raise a notification using NSNotificationCenter.  I am using 
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:                                        userInfo:repeats:]

I handle this in my AppDelegate class.  This works OK except when I am running code using MBProgressHUD - http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-heads-up-display-with-mbprogresshud.html
 which I think starts another thread.  Error occurs when it's Done delegate fires the same time as when code that reacts to the Notification is running.  I am pretty sure this is a threading issue but how do I avoid the situation

Answer (score 0):

You could use @synchronized on app delegate. Since app delegate is a singletone you'll have to critical sections guarded by it: one in "done delegate" and another in your app delegate.

More info in apple threading documents [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)

EDIT: [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html) link about threading and notifications is a good source of information for you.

EDIT 2: [this one](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/safe-threaded-design-and-inter-thread.html) is even better